# iPhone - Using a localized resource

Tags: iphone, resources, localization

I'm trying to display an html file into a UIWebView :

```
NSString *htmlPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"error.htm"];

NSError* error;
NSStringEncoding encoding;
NSString *htmlContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlPath usedEncoding:&encoding error:&error];

NSString* bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
[self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlContent baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:bundlePath]];
```

error.htm is localized. When using this method, no page is loaded. The htmlContent refers to myApp.app/error.htm. But all my error.htm files are in localized folders.
If I use another non localized HTML file (error2.htm, pure copy of error.htm), it is displayed.

How may I use the localized file ?

Comment: You probably need to assign to that NSStringEncoding. If that fails, you should probably check if the 'htmlContent' string is empty.

Comment: Do you get a warning when you compile? You shouldn't be ignoring it! Why are you doing that odd thing with the string encoding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating the path to the html file yourself using the root resource path and a string - the iPhone isn't psychic, how would it know that you have localised this file?

Try using

```
NSString *htmlPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"error" ofType:@"html"];
```

instead - this should deal with localised resources for you.

Answer (score 0):

Localization shouldn't be the problem - I'm loading localized HTML files perfectly fine using something like this:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"error" ofType:@"htm"];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path isDirectory:NO]];

// ...

[self.webView loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: Also, not sure if that could be your problem, but I have my localized files encoded as UTF16.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is not correct (and also didn't work for me) - 
this is the function to use for loading localized resource:

```
- (NSString *)pathForResource:(NSString *)name ofType:(NSString *)ext inDirectory:(NSString *)subpath forLocalization:(NSString *)localizationName;
```

the localizationName is the two characters localization language code.
BTW - you can get your default/current one by using:

```
return [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: perhaps your resource is incorrectly localized.

also [NSLocale currentLocale].localeIdentifier should work and is probably more correct rather than dig into standardUserDefaults.